# I have a "pywhatkit" python module attribute error.Can you help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, whatsapp

Pywhatkit is already installed successfully but it shows an **attribute** error in any attribute code. Can I fix it?
[image: Attribute error screenshot attached with this]

My tried code:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendmsg('071*******','Ado',15,48)
```

How I fix this:
I renamed my program file name "pywhatkit.py" to "anotername.py".

Thank you all answered people who help me to solve this!

Comment: You need to change your python file name, from 'pywhatkit' to another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scrolling through their github page ([link here](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit)), it seems like you are calling the wrong method `sendmsg` should be `sendwhatmsg`

Working code:

```
import pywhatkit
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('071*******','Ado',15,48)
```